# ORA-01791 Error on Select Distinct with order

Tags: oracle

I was reading others reports about this error but my example is different and inexplicable:

I simplified the test to two cases:

Case 1. Throw ORA-01791

```
SELECT DISTINCT pca_pca_id
  FROM SA_PRESTACIONES_FACTURADAS
 ORDER BY 1
```

Case 2. Finished succesfully

```
SELECT DISTINCT vda_drv_proceso
  FROM SA_PRESTACIONES_FACTURADAS presfa
 ORDER BY 1
```

I'm thinking in something related to configuration because in others instances the original query was working.

Comment: what happens when you add alias to table in first query 'SELECT DISTINCT pca_pca_id
  FROM SA_PRESTACIONES_FACTURADAS tbl
 ORDER BY 1' ?

Comment: Usually StackOverflow disapproves of images but it this case you should post a screenshot. I'm not saying I don't believe you, but some evidence of the weird behaviour would be good.

Comment: Aparently is related to Data Redaction in Oracle Database 12c

Comment: The error was escalated to DBA, and then Oracle so I lost the tracking, only I know is what I said in the previous post...It's solved now, (i guess disabling data redaction). I don't know if I must close this topic or how to help community...

Comment: If you can clearly explain what the issue actually was and how it was solved then you can write that up as an answer, and that might be useful to other people. But if you can't - and it sounds like you don't have the details - then it's probably better to delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I come back to close this issue.

With Data Redaction in Oracle Database 12c if you mask columns what are used in a select distinct you may face with the error ORA-01791.

It's reported at oracle support, I don't have full access so i leave the id: Doc ID 2274452.1